# Combine date and time from different rows

Tags: r

My start date column looks like something below. Some of it has both date and time while some have only either date or time, while the remaining are NA's.

The time and hour is supposed to be in the same row as the date, while the  should be the date and time from previous row.

```
      Start.Date      Values
11/6/2017\n07:00           a
3/22/2018\n06:38           b
       11/6/2017           c
           07:00           d
            <NA>           e
            <NA>           f
            <NA>           g
            <NA>           h
11/5/2017\n07:00           i
3/21/2018\n06:38           j
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
      Start.Date      Values
11/6/2017\n07:00           a
3/22/2018\n06:38           b
11/6/2017\n07:00           c
11/6/2017\n07:00           d
11/6/2017\n07:00           e
11/6/2017\n07:00           f
11/6/2017\n07:00           g
11/6/2017\n07:00           h
11/5/2017\n07:00           i
3/21/2018\n06:38           j
```

Is there anyway to do this? I tried using tidyr to extract it but I am not getting the desired outcome. Thank you!

Comment: Why `3rd` row Start.Date is `11/6/2017\n07:00` and not `3/22/2018\n06:38`?

Comment: Any chance to fix this closer to the source/at read-in? Those `\n` newlines don't look too good.

Comment: @MKR The date is not in the right arrangement and I need to standardized it in order to use lubridate().

Comment: @AkselA, I can't fix it closer to the source cause there are a few hundreds of this documents that I loop through with my scraper function.

Comment: @Tze Then even 2nd row should have value as `11/6/2017\n07:00`. Am  I correct?

Comment: @MKR about that, I used dplyr to arrange the other column (not listed in here) and my Start.Date ended up not in order. I was thinking of using lubridate() to change the format to myd_hms() and rearrange everything using the Start.Date.

Answer (score 0):

First try to convert `Start.Date` using `mdy_hm` function from `lubridate`. Then use `tidyr::fill` to update rows not containing valid date/time (i.e. `NA`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(Start.Date = mdy_hm(Start.Date)) %>%
  fill(Start.Date)

#             Start.Date Values
# 1  2017-11-06 07:00:00      a
# 2  2018-03-22 06:38:00      b
# 3  2018-03-22 06:38:00      c
# 4  2018-03-22 06:38:00      d
# 5  2018-03-22 06:38:00      e
# 6  2018-03-22 06:38:00      f
# 7  2018-03-22 06:38:00      g
# 8  2018-03-22 06:38:00      h
# 9  2017-11-05 07:00:00      i
# 10 2018-03-21 06:38:00      j
```

**Note:** The above answer is not matching with expectation of OP. Perhaps rows needs to be arrange correctly.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Start.Date      Values
'11/6/2017\n07:00'     a
'3/22/2018\n06:38'    b
11/6/2017           c
07:00               d
NA           e
NA           f
NA           g
NA           h
'11/5/2017\n07:00'     i
'3/21/2018\n06:38'     j",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: It doesn't match the expected output but thanks for the help! I'll try to clean it up manually.